# Extracting first and second number

Tags: regex, r

I want to fetch first number (76073) and second number (76078) from a string

```
"76073RMBA_S>76078SKYU_S"

str <- "76073RMBA_S>76078SKYU_S"
#a : first number
#b: second number
```

Comment: OK. Show us where you are stuck.

Comment: Quick way could be `stringi::stri_extract_all(str, regex = "\\d+")` or `regmatches(str, gregexpr("\\d+", str))` with base R

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach with `gsub` and `scan`.  We replace by matching the non-numeric characters (`\\D+`) and replace it with `,`, then `scan` the string by specifying `sep` as `,` to get a `numeric` vector.

```
head(scan(text=gsub("\\D+", ",", str), what=numeric(), sep=",", quiet=TRUE),2)
#[1] 76073 76078
```

---

Or using `strsplit`, we can split by non-numeric characters and convert the string vector output to `numeric`.

```
as.numeric(strsplit(str, "\\D+")[[1]])
#[1] 76073 76078
```